# FourSquare HereNow Venue API will return the checkin till how long?

Tags: foursquare

Suppose someone checked-in to my venue. And now if i hit the venue/{venueId}/herenow endpoint it will give me that checkin. If i again hit the same endpoint after 5 mins, i am still getting that check-in in response.

So after what time it will stop coming in the response ? (30 mins / 1 hour ?)

Answer (score 1):

A venue's `hereNow` will reflect a user's check-in there up until 3 hours later or the same user checks in somewhere else, whichever is sooner.